# Uma pergunta com várias dúvidas ou várias perguntas em sequência?

Tags: debate

Estou com uma dúvida em relação a Triggers, mas em 3 SGBDs diferentes.

Seriam 3 perguntas separadas ou poderia englobar em uma pergunta. Achei ruim a ideia de uma pergunta pois pode ter gente que entenda de Oracle e não de DB2 por exemplo, em contra partida, achei estranho postar 3 perguntas muito parecidas em sequencia

Comment: A dúvida é sobre as diferenças entre os SGBDs? Se for, faria sentido ter uma pergunta só.

Comment: @bfavaretto A dúvida é sobre o comportamento da linha inserida, na trigger de AfterUpdate em cada um deles, para saber se colunas não alteradas são retornadas ou não caso a trigger seja ativada por mais de uma colunas, seria algo especifico de cada um

Comment: Complicado, nenhuma solução parece 100% boa. E isso já aconteceu antes: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/289/o-que-fazer-com-perguntas-que-podem-ter-m%C3%BAltiplas-respostas

Comment: [Essa resposta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/294/5536) da referida pergunta é exatamente o meu problema ;)

Comment: Ou posso esperar uns 10 minutos entre cada uma delas, @bfavaretto

Comment: Ou 10 horas? :) Eu ainda não entendi por que você precisaria das 3 respostas. É mais uma curiosidade que um problema concreto?

Comment: @bfavaretto É um problema real, um deles o ajudou lá no chat, é que preciso fazer essa trigger para os 3 SGBDs, e fiquei em dúvida nos "new values" dos after update, mas estou pesquisando para ver se consigo encontrar para o DB2

Answer (score 6):

Em vez de pensar em como fazer as perguntas, pense em como você vai querer as respostas. Você quer que as respostas estejam relacionadas, sejam comparativas, sejam diferenças? Faça apenas uma pergunta. Note no entanto, que perguntas sobre diferenças entre sistemas nem sempre são bem aceitas no SO (pelo menos em Inglês).

Você quer a resposta de cada sistema, pois você vai comparar os resultados e não precisa de que quem responda o faça? Faça perguntas diferentes.

Visto que as perguntas serão semelhantes, você pode colocar links de uma pergunta para a outra e indicar que embora sejam semelhantes as perguntas são para sistemas diferentes. Isso vai ajudar a quem ler não achar que são duplicadas.